# How to clear graph inner connections so that only borders would be left?

Tags: c#, .net, graph, .net-4.5, graph-algorithm

I have a graph of `Node`s (points in space with `x` and `y` coordinates) connected to each other in form of a graph (each node has a `List<Node> others` that represent its connections):

[image]

How to select only nodes that belong to the graph out edges marked in red here?

Comment: I would love if LINQ has some shourt cuts for such operations...

Comment: What is unique about the red outlined nodes?

Comment: _each node has a List<Node> others that represent its connections_ I don't think you've given us enough information.  With only the list of which nodes are connected to which other ones, I could draw an equivalent graph with some of those nodes on the "outside" of your red lines.  Do you have actual **coordinates** for the nodes?  How was this graph produced?  What rules were followed in its production?...

Comment: How do you select nodes as **outers**? It's not easy to understand from this picture